# How can I get a textbox to update when a checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code, and I can't seem to figure out why its not working.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EQHRV/

JavaScript:

```
    function hourmin() {
        if (document.getElementById('hourmin').checked == 1){
            document.getElementById('total').value = "01:00";
        }else{
            document.getElementById('total').value = "00:00";
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <p>Total Time: <BR><input type="text" style="width:95%;" id="total" name="total" value="" readonly="readonly"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="hourmin" name="hourmin"  onclick="hourmin();">Pay Hour Minimum?
```

Comment: what is the error you're getting? i put it on codepend and it's working: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FblhA

Comment: JSFiddle + Firebug report that `hourmin` is not a function. Interesting.

Comment: @FDL configuring it with Pure JS and no-wrap (head) it works as expected.

Comment: `elm.checked` returns boolean. You don't need to check if it equals to 1 or 0.

Comment: check my updated answer to get the checkbox from event argument if you  cannot figure out if there is a duplicate id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong option in the JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/EQHRV/3/

The option onLoad will wrap your entire script into window.onload, so your functions will be unnacessible in the global scope.

```
window.onload = function(){
    //your code
}
```

Change it to

`No wrap - in HEAD` or `No wrap - in BODY`

[image]

---

You can also force your variables/functions to be available on the global scope by creating a reference on `window`

```
window.hourmin = function(){
    ...
}
```

---

But I would like to suggest to avoid using inline scripts like `onclick="etc()"`

http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/
http://www.unicodegirl.com/from-inline-events-to-addeventlistener.html

---

EDIT:

Possible problems that may be causing this to not work on your website

- elements id should be unique
- javascript is case sensitive `hourmin` is not the same as `hourMin`
- since you're using inline events the called function should be on global scope, make sure it is not nested inside another function
- check your document for syntax errors
- WebInspector is your friend

[Safari - WebInspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
[Chrome - DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/)
[Opera - Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/)

Comment: This fixed the fiddle, any idea why it wouldn't work on my site?

Comment: It should be working, try to put a `alert('Hi')` inside the hourmin function to see if it's been triggered

Comment: I did that and for some reason its not, still trying to figure out why.  My other functions are working so it is confusing me

Comment: So i can trigger the function using onkeyup="sum();" for a textbox. Any idea why it still won't work for a checkbox?

Comment: I got it to work by moving it to another div not sure why :(.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok, but I recommend you to use `onchange` instead of `onclick`

```
<p>Total Time: <BR><input type="text" style="width:95%;" id="total" name="total" value="" readonly="readonly"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="hourmin" name="hourmin"  onchange="hourmin()">Pay Hour Minimum?
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EQHRV/11/)

On your site, it does not work, it could be the problem of ***multiple elements with the same id***

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EQHRV/12/)

In this demo, I create another `div` with the same id: `hourmin`. You would see that it does not work correctly.

If you have problems figuring out whether there is a duplicate id. You could and ***should*** get the checkbox in the `event` argument `onchange="hourmin(event)`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EQHRV/13/)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at firebug or some js debugging tool, you can see that your function isn't found because it hasn't been loaded.

Change the place that JSFiddle puts your javascript to

Like this:

[image: JSFiddle javascript code placement]